# Can't retrieve metadata from BlobItem

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I'm struggling with fetching meta data from BlobItem when fetching Blobs from Azure storage.

I'm definitely missing something but can't to figure it out what or where

Here is simple block of code where I'm fetching BlobItems from test container.

Everything is fine on `var properties` as I did successfully fetch Metadata, but problem lies when I'm trying to fetch data for blob item inside while loop, it returns null

```
        var containerClient =  _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(AzureStorageHelpers.BlobContainers.Files);
        var properties = await containerClient.GetPropertiesAsync();

        var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobsAsync();
        var enumerator = blobs.GetAsyncEnumerator();

        var blobList = new List<BlobItem>();
        try
        {
            while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                var blobItem = enumerator.Current;
                var metaData = enumerator.Current.Metadata;
                var dwaw = blobItem.Metadata["Name"];
                blobList.Add(blobItem);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            await enumerator.DisposeAsync();
        }
```

I'm getting null value and on Azure I can clearly see that I have defined some test metadata properties.

[image]

I'm using **NET.Core 2.2** with N**uget Azure.Storage.Blobs(12.5.1)**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try passing the parameter while fetching Blobs:

```
var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobsAsync(BlobTraits.Metadata);
```

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list?tabs=dotnet#return-metadata)

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you